# Unresolved compilation problem: The method map is ambiguous for the type Dataset<Row>

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I try to make java client codes of apache spark 3.0.1. First belows are the pom.xml codes.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

And I make java client codes with spark structured streaming api

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("KafkaMongo_StrctStream").getOrCreate();
        
Dataset<Row> inputDF = spark.read().format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "topicForMongoDB").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load().selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)");
        
Encoder<Document> mongoEncode = Encoders.bean(Document.class);
Dataset<Row> tempDF = inputDF.map(row -> {    //map function throws the exception.
        String[] parameters = new String[row.mkString().split(",").length];
            
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        parameters = csvMapper.readValue(row.mkString(), String[].class);
            
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
        EntityMongoDB data = new EntityMongoDB();//LocalDate.parse(parameters[2], formatter), Float.valueOf(parameters[3]), parameters[4], parameters[5], parameters[6], parameters[7], parameters[8], parameters[9]);
            
        String jsonInString = csvMapper.writeValueAsString(data);

        Document doc = new Document(Document.parse(jsonInString));      
        return doc;
    }, mongoEncode).toDF();
```

But these codes can not run because of the below exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method map(Function1<Row,Document>, Encoder<Document>) is ambiguous for the type Dataset<Row>
```

I can not see any errors on these codes because these codes worked without exceptions on apache spark 2.4 version. These unresolved compilation exception are brought from the apache spark versions matters? Kindly inform me how to solve this issue.

**= Updated =**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.bson.Document;

import com.aaa.etl.pojo.EntityMongoDB;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
```

For your information, I also attach the EntityMongoDB class source,

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EntityMongoDB implements Serializable {

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate date;
    
    private float value;
    
    private String id;
    
    private String title;
    
    private String state;
    
    private String frequency_short;
    
    private String units_short;
    
    private String seasonal_adjustment_short;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing all of your imports?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Kindly check my updated part.

Comment: @JosephHwang can you please let me know how have you resolve this.  My code also works fine on earlier version of Spark but failing on latest version 3.x of Spark

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem,and solved it.
**Here is my codes**
before:

```
Dataset<Row> newData = dataModel.map(row -> {
    return row;
},Encoders.kryo(Row.class));
```

after:

```
Dataset<Row> newData = dataModel.map((MapFunction<Row,Row>)row -> {
    return row;
},Encoders.kryo(Row.class));
```

There is pertty less relate documents on the net,I`m not sure it is a good way. 
If you have any progress, please share with me.
**Best wishes**

Answer (score 0):

I was upgrading from Spark 2.x -> 3.x.  I found this error occurs when moving from scala 2.11 to 2.12, for example the artifact below has this problem too.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

The fix I found was to avoid the inline mapping.  In the example above you can split it into it's own MapFunction class.

```
public class DocumentMapper implements MapFunction<Row, Document> {
    @Override
    public Document call(Row row) throws Exception {
        String[] parameters = new String[row.mkString().split(",").length];
        
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        parameters = csvMapper.readValue(row.mkString(), String[].class);
        
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
        EntityMongoDB data = new EntityMongoDB();//LocalDate.parse(parameters[2], formatter), Float.valueOf(parameters[3]), parameters[4], parameters[5], parameters[6], parameters[7], parameters[8], parameters[9]);
        
        String jsonInString = csvMapper.writeValueAsString(data);

        Document doc = new Document(Document.parse(jsonInString));      
        return doc;
    }
}
```

Then reference this in the mapping call.

```
Dataset<Row> tempDF = inputDF.map(new DocumentMapper(), mongoEncode).toDF();
```

Hope this helps other upgraders out there.